# Travis CI - Multiproject structure

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci

My Android based repository has the following structure:

- main

  - project1
  - project2
  - project3

Each project has it's own gradle envoirement. I tried to setup Travis for this structure but I haven't found a solution until now.